# How do I resolve a "Executable not found!" error?

Tags: macos, launchd

I have upgraded from macOS 10.13.4 to macOS 10.14.1 (18B75) on a Mac mini (Late 2012), and now have one orphan file, and the corresponding Executable not found.

```
/System/Library/LaunchDaemons/com.apple.duetknowledged.plist
One orphan file found.
```

System Launch Daemons:     [failed]
com.apple.duetknowledged.plist (? ? ? - installed 2018-10-01) - /usr/local/libexec/duetknowledged: Executable not found!

Any recommendations on how to fix the problem would be appreciated greatly.

Comment: What are we looking at here (where does this report come from)? How does beachballing relate to the bold parts in the text? Please also have a look at the [FAQ] for details on how to write questions which attract answers.

Comment: That is a very long list of problems and not possible to answer in a single answer. Please break it down in separate questions.

Comment: Anything is /usr/local was not installed by apple what have you installed?

Comment: Thank you, Mark! 
Software installs (last 30 days):
    Logitech Options: (null) (installed 2018-10-11)
    Microsoft AutoUpdate: (null) (installed 2018-10-18)
    Memory Clean 2: 1.8 (installed 2018-10-20)
    Disk Cleanup Pro: 1.7.0 (installed 2018-10-28)

Answer (score 1):

This isn't something you need to be concerned with.

Files in `/System` are managed by Apple, and should not be modified. (In fact, they *cannot* be modified if SIP is enabled.) The fact that this one references a nonexistent file in `/usr/local` is unusual, but attempting to "fix" this is likely to cause more problems than it solves.